# Does multiplying by -1 plus a rotation of \pi change the argument of a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

This is prompted by the exercise on page 7 of Needham's Visual Complex Analysis: show that 
$$\frac{(1+i)^5}{(\sqrt 3+i)^2}
 = -\sqrt 2 \;\angle-(\pi/12).$$ 
Algebraic and modulus-argument approaches seemed to return different answers.

Comment: I think the edited format matches the book now.

Comment: It's hard to guess why you got different results from the two approaches. Perhaps if you edited the question to show all of your work, someone might spot where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to remember that Needham is using $\angle$ as part of a
modulus-argument notation; not everyone uses that notation.
Elsewhere you might see the problem expressed this way:
$$\frac{(1+i)^5}{(\sqrt 3+i)^2} = -\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi/12}.$$

This should come out the same whether you use algebraic
or modulus-argument methods to compute the left-hand side.
Just keep in mind that the right-hand side is expressed in a somewhat
unusual fashion; note that
$$ -\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi/12} = \sqrt 2 e^{i(11\pi/12)},$$
where the form on the right-hand side corresponds better to the usual 
modulus-argument format.

Answer (score 0):

You could say

$1+i = \sqrt 2 e^{\frac \pi4 i}\\
\sqrt 3+i = 2 e^{\frac {\pi}6 i}\\
\frac{(1+i)^5}{ (\sqrt 3 + i)^2} = \frac{2^{\frac 52}e^{\frac {5\pi}{4}i}}{2^2e^{\frac {2\pi}{6}i}} = 2^{\frac 12} e^{\frac {11\pi}{12}i} = -\frac {\sqrt 3}{2} - \frac {1}{2} +(\frac {\sqrt 3}2 - \frac {1}{2})i$

alternatively

$\frac {(1+i)^5}{(\sqrt 3 + i)^3} = \frac {1 + 5i - 10 - 10i + 5 + i}{3 + 2\sqrt 3i - 1}\\
 \frac {-4 - 4i}{2 + 2\sqrt 3i} = \frac {(-4 - 4i)(2-2\sqrt 3 i)}{16}\\
\frac {-8 - 8\sqrt3 + (-8+8\sqrt 3) i}{16} =\frac {-1}{2} -\frac {\sqrt 3}{2} + (-\frac{1}{2} +\frac {\sqrt 3}{2})i $